# The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

My route is correctly configured, and my methods have the decorated tag.  I still get "The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'" message?

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public string Auth(string username, string password)
{
  // Décoder les paramètres reçue.
  string decodedUsername = username.DecodeFromBase64();
  string decodedPassword = password.DecodeFromBase64();

  return "value";
}
```

Here are my routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AuthentificateRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/game/authentificate;{username};{password}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Game",
                    action = "Auth", 
                    username = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                    password = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Please use the attributes from the System.Web.**Http** namespace on your WebAPI actions:

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string Auth(string username, string password)
    {...}
```

The reason why it doesn't work is because you were using the attributes that are from the **MVC** namespace  `System.Web.Mvc`.  The classes in the `System.Web.Http` namespace are for **WebAPI**.

Comment: Damn.. thanks ! i was about to get crazy lol incredible how you can waste time on such small things..

Comment: Indeed, an explanation of **why** this is the correct answer is certainly necessary here!

Comment: Edited answer with explanation.

Comment: can I specify   [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")] and 
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]  in RouteConfig.cs so that I no need add this in each API.

Comment: Why did I need to do this in only one of my 10 apis for this project? I created the api in exactly the same way as in the other 9 apis. How frustrating.

Comment: Why is it allowed to specify GET/POST in AcceptVerbs but not do [System.Web.Http.HttpPost] ?

Comment: It worked. Is anybody else happy with Microsoft naming spree? I guess they must have very expensive training somewhere that explains the difference.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the route signature was different from the method parameter. I had id, but I was accepting documentId as parameter, that caused the problem.

```
[Route("Documents/{id}")]   <--- caused the webapi error
[Route("Documents/{documentId}")] <-- solved
public Document Get(string documentId)
{
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Resolved this issue by using `http(s)` when accessing the endpoint.  The route I was accessing was not available over `http`.  So I would say verify the protocols for which the route is available.

Answer (score 3):

just use this attribute

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
```

not need this line of code:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue.. I already had 4 controllers going and working just fine but when I added this one it returned "The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'". 
I tried everything here and in a couple other relevant articles but was indifferent to the solution since, as Dan B. mentioned in response to the answer, I already had others working fine.

I walked away for a while, came back, and immediately realized that when I added the Controller it was nested under the "Controller" class and not "ApiController" class that my other Controllers were under. I'm assuming I chose the wrong scaffolding option to build the .cs file in Visual Studio. So I included the System.Web.Http namespace, changed the parent class, and everything works without the additional attributes or routing.