# Why do I get a 'selected resource doesn't support HTTP method get' error when making a put request to webapi service?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I've got a web api application that I've deployed to 3 machines. It runs fine on two of them, but on one whenever I try to make a put request I get this error:

The selected resource does not support HTTP method 'get'.

The is weird because I'm making a put request, not a get.

The controller has a method for put requests:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/users/current/{userId:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(int userId) {
        _unitOfWork.Users.SetCurrentUser(userId);
        _unitOfWork.Complete();
        return Ok();
    }
```

The calling code from angular is:

```
coreAPIservice.SetCurrentUser = function(userId) {
    return $http.put(serviceURLRoot + 'api/users/current/' + userId).success(function() {
        console.log('coreAPIservice.SetCurrentUser Success');
    });
}
```

Is there an IIS setting that needs to be changed?

Comment: Whats the fully qualified namespace of your HttpPut attribute? Hopefully its not System.Web.Mvc like in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765636/the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-get).

Comment: @BBauer42 No, it's System.Web.Http

Comment: What does the http put Url sent by Angular looks like with Fiddler (or by adding a `console.log(serviceURLRoot + 'api/users/current/' + userId)` in your code)? Does it match exactly your route? Could it be that your `serviceURLRoot` variable is missing a "/" at the end?