# How to create GET method in API controller with parameters (e.g. sort query or search query)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an API controller and GET method like this :

```
public IEnumerable<CountryDTO> GetContries(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    return countryRepository.GetCos(sortOrder,  searchString);
}
```

but when I try to get url api/countries
I`ve got an error like:
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765636/the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-get

Comment: Unfortunately ,no(

Comment: [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<CountryDTO> GetContries(string sortOrder, string searchString)
        {

            return countryRepository.GetCos(sortOrder,  searchString);
        }

Comment: and web config:  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CountryRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/country;{sortOrder};{searchString}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Country",
                    action = "GetContries", 
                    sortOrder = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                    searchString = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly mark the method `[HttpGet]` and make the following change to your method.

```
[HttpGet]    
public IEnumerable GetCountries(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
   return countryRepository.GetCos(sortOrder, searchString).ToList();
}
```

Also, I would recommend before you make the change, simply test your method using a tool like SOAPUI or Fiddler. See if you are able to get a response. That way you know for sure that problem is not in the basics of the method formation.

```
[HttpGet]    
public string GetCountries(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
   return ("returns list of countries");
}
```

Comment: Is this the way you pass the params ? 

http://yourhost/api/countries/?sortOrder=somevalue&searchString=somevalue

Comment: Did you make the change and add the [HttpGet] verb and test ??