# The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET' in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a web API (.NET Framework 4.0, MVC Web Application, visual studio 2010 sp1)

And there is my `WebApiConfig` code:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And for example this is one of my Controller's Methode Code:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
[ActionName("GetAccountTypeById")]
public static clsAccountType GetAccountTypeById(int AccountTypeId)
{
    SqlParameter[] param = { new SqlParameter("@Id", AccountTypeId) };
    DataTable dt = null;
    dt = Execute.ExecuteSelect("SP_GetAccountTypeById", param);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {clsAccountType item = new clsAccountType(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Id"]), dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
        return item;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

The problem is when I call this URL:

```
http://localhost:1387/api/AccountType/GetAccountTypeById
```

From browser show me this error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Comment: Because you have `[AcceptVerbs("Post")]`

Comment: and What are you suggesting

Comment: a **static** action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765636/the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-get)

Comment: thank you so much i did not notice that point(Static action)

Answer (score 0):

A browser cannot issue POST requests, so when you click the link in a browser you actually issue a GET request and that's why you see the error.

You need to use a tool like Postman which allows you to issue any type of request you need, in order to test your endpoints.