# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' appears after an inner exception

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, rest

The issue is that this code gives inner exception and when it goes to the url (`api/brand`) it gives this error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

I have tried many solutions but non are working.

```cs
public class BrandController : ApiController
{
    public List<Brands> DetailsGet()
    {
        EFDBFirstDatabaseEntities db = new EFDBFirstDatabaseEntities();
        try
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            List<Brands> brand = db.Brands.ToList();
            return brand;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.InnerException.Message));
            }
            else
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

This is model class code:

```
namespace EntityPractice.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Brands
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Brands()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<Products>();
        }
    
        public long BrandID { get; set; }
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the following post: [The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12765636/6630084)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following post: [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

It is necessary take care to handle any exceptions raised in Web API methods depend on your method functionality.

In example above instead of `throw ex;` it is necessary to construct and return some instance of `HttpResponseException()` too.