# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' but using 'POST'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My route is correctly configured as I already saw it in another questions.
Web API uses `MapHttpRoute`, and it uses `System.Web.Http`. I decorated my Actions with `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]` but it seems not to work and it returns the error message:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

I tried this solution `[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` as I see here on the same question. [The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765636/the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-get) and it worked.

But on the **API Help Page**, this is what I see[image: Red Circle]

the **METHOD** of the Action is `GET` that that should be `POST`.

Maybe I am missing something that should not or should be implemented on the Action I am working with.

Here is my code in the Controller.

```
    [HttpPost, Route("DestroySession/{userID}", Name = "DestroySession"), AcceptVerbs("GET" , "POST")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DestroyUserSession(string userID)
    {
        SystemResult systemResult = new SystemResult();
        await Task.Run(() => {
            IAbstractLogic<UserInput, SystemResult> systemProcess = new LogoutLogic();
            UserInput userInput = new UserInput
            {
                UserID = userID
            };
            systemResult = systemProcess.doProcess(userInput);
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new 
        { 
            message = systemResult.ResultMessage, status = systemResult.ResultCode == 0 
        });
    }
```

And here is my `WebApiConfig`

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Regards

Answer (score -1):

Whooosh! It seems that my code is working very fine. I just tested it in POSTMAN and it literally works. All I can say is that if your request is to `POST` something. you need a third party application to test it out. Testing it on the browser alone gives you so much problem.

Comment: How were you "testing it in the browser"? Your question contains no detail on that. If you were typing the url host.com/api/users/destroysession/1 then that will have been doing a GET. POST needs to be done by script or a form on the page. You can look in the network tab of the dev tools to see what request was issued. Not that I expect asp would have lied about it..

Comment: @CaiusJard, just putting the values of the arguments on the URL.

Comment: Yeah, that always does a GET

Comment: OOoooow...!!!! Now I get it. Thank you Sir. @CaiusJard

Comment: As an aside, you should maybe DELETE, because the request doesn't contain any body data. Typically we use POST or PATCH for updates, DELETE for deletes, PUT for inserts. It is best to try and keep GET for read only accesses that don't change anything. There was some thing a while ago where (google?) thought it would be a good idea to prefetch every GETtable thing on a page to speed up browsing "in case that thing was clicked", which caused problems for all those apps where GET modified data..

Comment: @CaiusJard , Should I use `GET` when I request for the updating of the data?

Comment: Er, no i think as per above it is sensible to keep a policy of using GET only for read-only things that do not perform updates that would change what is returned next time GET is called. By all means update some "last accessed on" date in a GET, but don't go editing the user name or whatever.. strive for following that convention of POST = update, PUT = insert, DELETE = delete, GET = select